# Change content in div based on logic using React

Tags: reactjs

I'm failing to understand how to update the content inside my render function based on logic from inside of a function. Do I have to return a whole new render function in order to do so? If so, that seems counter intuitive with React's framework of state & props and such...

Here's what I've tried:

```
  tick() {
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      minutes: prevState.seconds + 1,
    }));
    if(this.state.minutes > this.state.targetGoal){
      console.log("NONONONONO");
      return (<div>SOMETHING NEW</div>); //update content inside render()
    }
  }

  async componentDidMount() {
    this.interval = setInterval(() => this.tick(), 1000);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    clearInterval(this.interval);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div style={divStyle}>
        <div>Your Second Count: {this.state.seconds}</div>
        <habitlab-logo-v2></habitlab-logo-v2>
        <br/>
        <close-tab-button></close-tab-button>
      </div>

    );
  }
}
```

Comment: What happens with this code? An error message? Unexpected output?

Comment: What a React component renders is based on its props/state, and state/prop changes trigger re-renders. So for your use case something like a boolean called `targetReached` in the state (initially false), then when the state minutes exceeds the target goal, change it to true. And in your render JSX have something like `{this.state.targetReached === true && <div>SOMETHING NEW</div>}`. Also, be aware that `setState()` is asynchronous, so don't call it then expect the state to be changed in the following lines of code in that same function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few issues.

As [@Jayce444 has pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51528864/change-content-in-div-based-on-logic-using-react/51529378#comment90026657_51528864), you need to change a state to trigger `render` to re-render.

So create a new flag (say `isOvertime`) to trigger the render to fire.

```
 tick() {
    this.setState(
      prevState => ({
        seconds: prevState.seconds + 1
      }),
      () => {
        if (this.state.seconds > this.state.targetGoal) {
          console.log("NONONONONO");
          // return <div>SOMETHING NEW</div>; //update content inside render()
          this.setState({ isOvertime: true });
        }
      }
    );
  }
```

And in the `render`, you show a component depending on the `isOvertime`.

```
render() {
    const { isOvertime, seconds } = this.state;

    return (
      <div>
        {isOvertime ? (
          <div>Time Over Man!</div>
        ) : (
          <div>Your Second Count: {seconds}</div>
        )}
        <input
          type="number"
          value={this.state.targetGoal}
          onChange={e => this.setState({ targetGoal: e.target.value })}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
```

Here is the full source. (demo availabe on CodeSandBox).
[image: Edit zkn0lkyvjx]

**Output**
[image]

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import "./styles.css";

class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    interval: 0,
    seconds: 0,
    targetGoal: 4,
    isOvertime: false
  };

  tick() {
    this.setState(
      prevState => ({
        seconds: prevState.seconds + 1
      }),
      () => {
        if (this.state.seconds > this.state.targetGoal) {
          console.log("NONONONONO");
          // return <div>SOMETHING NEW</div>; //update content inside render()
          this.setState({ isOvertime: true });
        }
      }
    );
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    const interval = setInterval(() => this.tick(), 1000);
    this.setState({ interval });
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    clearInterval(this.interval);
  }

  render() {
    const { isOvertime, seconds } = this.state;

    return (
      <div>
        {isOvertime ? (
          <div>Time Over Man!</div>
        ) : (
          <div>Your Second Count: {seconds}</div>
        )}
        <input
          type="number"
          value={this.state.targetGoal}
          onChange={e => this.setState({ targetGoal: e.target.value })}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Comment: fix bug: `clearInterval(this.interval);` -> `clearInterval(this.state.interval);`. Also after `this.setState({ isOvertime: true });` you should clear interval to avoid infinity ticks (see console)